# How to find a rate at which data is growing with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where there is a column which contains the new number of covid cases per day.
After plotting that I get this graph :

[image: Covid cases 2021 graph]

Now I want to find out at what rate the cases are growing so how can I do this ?

Comment: The graph is irrelevant, the rate is a function of the data. Also, what time frame? Daily / weekly? It would help to see [ask] and [reprex].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate at which cases grow will be: `(cases in current day - cases in previous day) / cases in previous day`

There are several ways to do this. The easiest is to use `df.pct_change()`